# Excel 2010 Chart Data Range Reference

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010

I'm sure this question has inevitably been asked and answered but despite a couple of days of searching I haven't been able to come up with a solution.

In excel (2010) I have a section of data referring to test results. The data looks roughly like this:

[image]

Each run inserts a new line at the top (row 2) with the latest results. From this I am trying to produce a chart that shows only the results from the last 7 runs, so the data in B1:E8. I can do by either direct reference, named range or converting to a table. The problem with the first two methods are that when I insert a new line under the headers the range then splits so that I have B1:E1 and B3:E9. The table method is slightly better in that it includes the newly inserted row but keeps the range set to the same bottom row (so it ends up referencing 8 rows of data).

Am i missing something obvious here? I'd prefer the data to be listed like this with the newest on the top, but I'm sure I can change it so the newest is at the bottom if anyone has a good idea!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is data inserted? Manually or from within a macro? If is a macro, can you control it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT formula on another worksheet to capture part of your table from Sheet1, like this:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!B1:E8")
```

And then specify that as your chart data range.

Just remember to use `INDIRECT` as array formula:

1. Enter `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!B1:E8")` in `Sheet2!B1` cell.
2. Select B1:E8 range.
3. Press F2 and then Ctrl-Shift-Enter to make it an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Pivot Chart.

You can apply a filter on these charts to only look at the Top X results.  So if you filter to show Top 7 by Date, then this should do the trick.

You might need to lookup a quick tutorial on Pivots and Pivot Charts if you don;t have any experience though.

They are incredibly valuable though, so I would recommend it regardless.

Comment: I'll have to find a pivot table tutorial and see how I get on. Thanks for the tip and I'll let you know!